# How to control/force iOS system volume [cordova]

Tags: ios, cordova, volume

We are developing a hybrid mobile application for the marine industry. 
The app is made to play an alarm in case of a man overboard.

To make sure the alarm is heard we need to force the volume to a 100% regardless of user settings. It's literally a matter of life and death.
While developing we've used this excellent plugin: https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-plugin-volume-control

Unfortunately we can't even get the app trough Testflight using that plugin.

So my question to you Stack overflow: Is there any way to force the system volume regardless of settings in an Cordova app? (we're using Ionic)

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MPVolumeView
This is the method we use.

```
+ (void) setSystemVolume:(float)volume {

    MPVolumeView* volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] init] autorelease];
    UISlider* volumeViewSlider = nil;
    for (UIView *view in [volumeView subviews]){
        if ([view.class.description isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]){
            volumeViewSlider = (UISlider*)view;
            break;
        }
    }
    [volumeViewSlider setValue:volume animated:YES];
    [volumeViewSlider sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: He Paul, thanks for pitching in. You mean I should make the above into a Cordova plugin?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, @JasonSchot?